# What are the 'averages' in Graylog extractor metrics?

Tags: graylog3

Using Graylog v3.3.5:

When I look at the metric details of an input's extractor it has these average values:

Metrics
3,684,359 total invocations since boot, averages: NaN, 0.67, 42.04.

Can anyone define what this is an average of?

The rest of the metrics look like this:
[GraylogExtractorMetrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfAB4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's respectively the One/Five/Fifteen minute rate for this extractor (rate=invocations).

You can see that [in the code](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/blob/6ca35c9a6610bd8f9cebbdacdfc49511db9d4137/graylog2-web-interface/src/components/extractors/ExtractorsListItem.jsx#L185) :

```java
       {numeral(metrics.total.rate.one_minute).format('0,0.[00]')},{' '}
       {numeral(metrics.total.rate.five_minute).format('0,0.[00]')},{' '}
       {numeral(metrics.total.rate.fifteen_minute).format('0,0.[00]')}.
```

The rate is a [RateMetricsResponse](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/blob/23e4856988bb856644c0734e5bdbe0f5b3354f83/graylog2-server/src/main/java/org/graylog2/shared/metrics/MetricUtils.java#L117) which eventually brings us in [com.codahale.metrics.Timer](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/apidocs/com/codahale/metrics/Timer.html), where we can see more details about the metrics, e.g:

> **getFifteenMinuteRate()**
>
> Returns the fifteen-minute exponentially-weighted moving average rate
> at which events have occurred since the meter was created.